# How to get e-mails to work on phpBB with CentOS 6? Experiencing PHP Error

Tags: email, centos, centos6, phpbb, phpbb3

So, I have a phpBB forum on CentOS 6, however there is a problem. E-mails are simply not working.

**I tried using e-mails on domain such as admin@domain.com, and I would get this error:**

```
    E-mail error
» EMAIL/PHP/mail()
/adm/index.php
```

**so I trued using SMTP with different SMTP hosts and settings, nothing has worked, I would simply get this error:**

```
        E-mail error
    » EMAIL/SMTP
    /adm/index.php

Could not connect to smtp host : 0 : php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution

Errno 2: fsockopen(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution at [ROOT]/includes/functions_messenger.php line 1030<br />
Errno 2: fsockopen(): unable to connect to smtp.mail.com:25 (php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution) at [ROOT]/includes/functions_messenger.php line 1030
```

**I got the errors from PHP Error Log from PHP**

Oddly enough, the e-mails appear on my VPS in var/spool/mail/root file.

2 people have told be that this may be a DNS issue, I suspect this being true, as I, for some reason, couldn't use "wget" on my VPS, so I set Nameservers in /etc/resolv.conf and suddenly another problem I was experiencing, "could not get latest phpBB version" or something like that, was fixed. So, if that was fixed with such a solution, I would assume this would have something to do with it too.

And, I asked my host about it, they said "everything is virtualized" and how they have no actual control over it (in a sense that it is their configuration's fault) and how they do not support 3rd party software, even though this is not a software issue. And prior to that they said that they talked to "level 3 Linux admin" and how the admin said it is PHP/Apache issue.

I am losing my mind over this. It is a good machine for a good price with a game panel as we are hosting a game server, and it would really be a bother to move it all elsewhere.

**Also, full talk and information on phpBB forums can be found here:**
https://www.phpbb.com/community/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=2257586

Answer (score 0):

Check your SMTP settings, make sure its set to the correct client (both on your DNS and within phpbb in General-Client Communication-Email Settings). If you have to use an authenticated account, verify that the username and password you are using is correct by typing it into a word doc to see spelling and copy/pasting it into the fields. In some cases, SMTP will only work with authenticated accounts.

Comment: "I tried using e-mails on domain such as admin@domain.com, and I would get this error:" -> I have obviously tried without SMTP and with SMTP, I have already said that I have tried multiple SMTP servers on multiple ports, tried every combination possible, and same error appears for SMTP, and without SMTP, using my board as sending e-mail, which should work on its own, I get the error which is first in the post. Not helpful, I wouldn't be running forums if I were such a clunk not to be able to type correct SMTP settings.